# Simulate external stroke ::before pseudo elements: problem with transparent text

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I find it difficult to believe that there is no standard and simple (and browser-independent) way to put a stroke effect around the *outside* of text using CSS.

We do have `-webkit-text-stroke` but for some odd reason the stroke is centred around the *border* of the text rather than *outside it*, as [bemoaned here](https://css-tricks.com/text-stroke-stuck-middle/#article-header-id-0).

So I'm trying to implement a workaround based on [this idea](https://www.petercarrero.com/examples/stroke/), which places the stroked text in a pseudo element behind the original un-stroked text.  I've demonstrated this in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lqsnkad5/), with the following code:

```js
var jQueryAttr = function(selector, attr, setterFunction) {
  document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach((el, i) => {
    el.setAttribute(attr, setterFunction.call(el, i, attr));
  });
};

jQueryAttr('.myclass', 'data-myclass', function(index, attr) {
  return this.innerHTML;
});
```

```css
body {
  background: none;
}

.basic {
  color: rgba(186, 218, 85, 1);
  font: 2.5em Georgia, serif;
}

.myclass {
  position: relative;
  background: transparent;
  z-index: 0;
}

.myclass::before {
  content: attr(data-myclass);
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 0.2em rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  z-index: -1;
}

.anotherclass {
  -webkit-text-stroke: 0.2em rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

```html
<p class="basic">Text without any stroke</p>
<p class="myclass basic">Text with outer stroke</p>
<p class="anotherclass basic">Without the trick applied</p>
```

This works fine, except that if the text itself has some transparency then you see the dark stroke underneath, as shown in [this variant](https://jsfiddle.net/Lqsnkad5/1/) (the only change is to peg the opacity of the text back to 0.3).  As you can see, the black from the stroked element is leaching through into the text (in the top line).

So is there another neat trick to use to overcome this problem?  I guess it's possible to add another pseudo element between the stroked layer and the un-stroked layer, with a pure white text (or one to match the background), but I'd like to apply this technique in a context where I *don't know the colour of the background in advance*... e.g. where this is laid over an arbitrary user-selected image.  For this reason, I've set the `background` of the `body` to `none` in the above example.

Answer (score 13):

Here is an idea where you can consider `mix-blend-mode` and a combination of text-shadow to approximate this. The tricky part is to adjust the shadow in case you want a bigger stroke:

```css
.text > span {
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-size:60px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color:#fff; /*use white*/
  /*create the stroke around text*/
  text-shadow:
    2px 0  0px #000,
    0 2px 0px #000,
    2px 2px 0px #000,
    -2px 0 0px #000,
    0 -2px 0px #000,
    -2px -2px 0px #000,
    -2px 2px 0px #000,
    2px -2px 0px #000;
  mix-blend-mode: darken; /*everything is more dark than white so we always see the background */
}
.text {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:20px;
  background:linear-gradient(to right,red, blue);
}
```

```html
<div class="text"><span>Some text here</span></div>
```

Using CSS variable will probably make it easier to adjust:

```css
.text > span {
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-size:60px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color:#fff; /*use white*/
  /*create the stroke around text*/
  text-shadow:
    var(--s,2px) 0  var(--c,0) #000,
    0 var(--s,2px) var(--c,0) #000,
    var(--s,2px) var(--s,2px) var(--c,0) #000,
    calc(-1*var(--s,2px)) 0 var(--c,0) #000,
    0 calc(-1*var(--s,2px)) var(--c,0) #000,
    calc(-1*var(--s,2px)) calc(-1*var(--s,2px)) var(--c,0) #000,
    calc(-1*var(--s,2px)) var(--s,2px) var(--c,0) #000,
    var(--s,2px) calc(-1*var(--s,2px)) var(--c,0) #000;
  mix-blend-mode: darken; /*everything is more dark than white so we always see the background */
}
.text {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:20px;
  background:linear-gradient(to right,red, blue);
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="text"><span>Some text here</span></div>

<div class="text" style="--s:4px;--c:2px;background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/800/600?image=1069)"><span>Some text here</span></div>

<div class="text" style="--s:6px;--c:4px;background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/800/600?image=1051)"><span>Some text here</span></div>
```

If you want a transparent color for the text you can duplicate it using pseudo element:

```css
.text > span {
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-size:60px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
}
.text > span::before,
.text > span::after {
  content:attr(data-text);
}
.text > span::before {
  color:#fff; /*use white*/
  /*create the stroke around text*/
  text-shadow:
    var(--s,2px) 0  var(--c,0) #000,
    0 var(--s,2px) var(--c,0) #000,
    var(--s,2px) var(--s,2px) var(--c,0) #000,
    calc(-1*var(--s,2px)) 0 var(--c,0) #000,
    0 calc(-1*var(--s,2px)) var(--c,0) #000,
    calc(-1*var(--s,2px)) calc(-1*var(--s,2px)) var(--c,0) #000,
    calc(-1*var(--s,2px)) var(--s,2px) var(--c,0) #000,
    var(--s,2px) calc(-1*var(--s,2px)) var(--c,0) #000;
  mix-blend-mode: darken; /*everything is more dark than white so we always see the background */
}
.text > span::after {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  color:rgba(0,255,0,0.4); 
}
.text {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:20px;
  background:linear-gradient(to right,red, blue);
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="text"><span data-text="Some text here"></span></div>

<div class="text" style="--s:4px;--c:2px;background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/800/600?image=1069)"><span data-text="Some text here"></span></div>

<div class="text" style="--s:6px;--c:4px;background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/800/600?image=1051)"><span data-text="Some text here"></span></div>
```

Comment: In your approach, if we did actually want a particular colour for the text (not completely transparent), e.g. `rgba(186, 218, 85, 0.5)`, then would you suggest using the `::before` trick as per my post in order to place the coloured text (without stroke) on top, with the background (stroked) below?  Also, I've tried the multi-shadow workaround before (with more than 4 or 8 shadows... for a smooth effect) but the reason I dismissed it is partly because I need to control the opacity of the stroke... difficult to achieve with overlapping shadows where opacity tends to build up to `1.0`.

Comment: @drmrbrewer yes correct, this is the drawback of using shadow in this situation. Not easy to control and difficult to add opacity .. for your text color, yes I would use a pseudo element with the text above (or below) the transparent parent with some opacity ... by the way, I will try to edit my answer in case I found a trick for the opacity

Comment: And what happens if there is no background?

Comment: @drmrbrewer you will have the white .. blend consider two colors .. the trick when using white and darken is that in all the case we will pick the background since it's the darkest one (everything is more dark than white) ... with no background the white will get picked

Comment: OK thanks. One of the use cases is to generate a PNG (with opacity), and then to overlay that onto another image.  So, there is no background present when the PNG is rendered, only after.  I guess this means that your solution wouldn't work in that context?  I have certainly learnt a lot from it, however, not least the ability to pass parameters into CSS variables...!

Comment: @drmrbrewer I am not able to visualize your use case .... you can probably create a code here: https://jsfiddle.net so I can better see it?

Comment: It's just the same as the original jsfiddle I created, but with no background: https://jsfiddle.net/h3rou75s/.  If we capture that to PNG, preserving alpha, then we can lay that PNG onto top of a background later.  So the background is not available when the html/css is rendered.

Comment: @drmrbrewer I have included the example with transparent color text

Comment: You may want to add `white-space:nowrap` for your last example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFcxY.png Yes, sorry I had non standard window size...

Comment: @Kaiido no, I should add display:inline-block, forget it .. the wrapping is needed and should work fine but pseudo element on inline element aren't good. (edited)

Answer (score 6):

The easiest, and with best browser support might actually be SVG.
You can set up approximately the same thing you did with the ::before, with the difference that the background stroked version can have a mask, which will let only the outer-line visible.
From there, you can simply append a copy of the same text over, and you'll be able to apply the opacity as you wish, both on the stroke and the fill:

```css
body{
  background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/800/200?image=1051);
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
svg {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.textStroke {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 12px;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
}
.visibleText {
  fill: rgba(186, 218, 85, 1);
  transition: fill-opacity .5s linear;
}
.visibleText:hover {
  fill-opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg width="350">
  <defs>
    <!-- we type it only once -->
    <text x="10" y="55" id="txt">Text with outline</text>
    <mask id="mymask">
      <!-- white => visible, black => tansparent -->
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="450" height="70" fill="#FFF"></rect>
      <use xlink:href="#txt" fill="#000"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <!-- our stroked text, with the mask -->
  <use xlink:href="#txt" mask="url(#mymask)" class="textStroke"/>
  <!-- fill version -->
  <use xlink:href="#txt" class="visibleText"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: agree, I was sure SVG would easily solve this. Too bad we cannot apply opacity to the stroke because of the overlap (OP also wanted this like commented on my answer)

Comment: yes but it will lead to non-uniform color because we will have overlap between stroke of adjacent letters.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Oh I see now, on Chrome... stoopids. Works fine on FF, I'll check what happens there, but setting `opacity`works everywhere:https://jsfiddle.net/rv7sjLof/

Comment: ah again the conflit between Chrome and Fiferox .. and yes forget the opacity which is trivial here. I was trying to use rgba colors :x

Comment: For the text's stroke-opacity, that would be a Chrome bug, I'll open one when I get time to find the regression range (webkit as it correct, so it might be a regression). [They do it correctly for pathes](https://jsfiddle.net/eujpo27q/). Adn while I don't see why couldn't control the `opacity` of each element (stroke & fill) rather than controlling the alpha value of their <color>, it can also be achieved even on buggy Chrome by using [two masks](https://jsfiddle.net/rv7sjLof/2/) But then we can [have fun](https://jsfiddle.net/rv7sjLof/3/).

Answer (score 2):

### Solution using SVG filters

To get a stroke around the text, you can use a combined SVG filter consisting of successively applied filters: `feMorphology`, `feComposite` and `feColorMatrix`.

```css
body{
  background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/800/800?image=1061);
  background-size:cover;
  font-family: serif;
  
}
```

```html
<svg  viewBox="0 0 350 350" >
  <defs>
    <filter id="groupborder" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
            x="-20%" y="-20%" width="300" height="300">
      <feMorphology operator="dilate" in="SourceAlpha"
                    radius="5" result="e1" />
      <feMorphology operator="dilate" in="SourceAlpha"
                    radius="2" result="e2" />
      <feComposite in="e1" in2="e2" operator="xor"
                   result="outline"/>
      <feColorMatrix type="matrix" in="outline"
                     values="0 0 0 0 0.1
                             0 0 0 0 0.2
                             0 0 0 0 0.2
                             0 0 0 1 0" result="outline2"/>
      <feComposite in="outline2" in2="SourceGraphic"
                   operator="over" result="output"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <g id="group" filter="url(#groupborder)">
    <text x="10" y="100"  stroke-width="1" fill="#1D3A56"  font-family="serif" font-size="30" font-weight="700" > Text with outline </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

The CSS-property [paint-order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/paint-order) could do the trick:

```css
.stroke {
  -webkit-text-stroke: 0.2em rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  paint-order: stroke fill;
}

.basic {
  color: rgba(186, 218, 85, 1);
  font: 2.5em Georgia, serif;
}
```

```html
<span class="basic">Text without stroke</span><br>
<span class="basic stroke">Text with stroke</span>
```

> Note: This is an [experimental technology](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/MDN/Contribute/Guidelines/Conventions_definitions#Experimental)
>
> Unfortunately its **not supported** by every browser ([browser compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/paint-order#Browser_compatibility)) and the behavior could change in the future.

---

The result will look like this in Firefox 65.0.2:
[image: screenshot of the result]

Comment: can you share a screenshot of the result so we can see how it looks? the support seems very poor

Comment: Good news: The browsersupport seems to be raising. :)