# How to use both text-shadow and linear-gradient for text?

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I try to use them both but it fails..

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 72px;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, black 50%, orange 50%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
}
```

```html
<h1>Heading 1</h1>
```

Using only linear-gradient without text-shadow:
[image]

Using only text-shadow without linear-gradient:
[image]

Using both:
[image]

Comment: Is the 2nd one, the text-shadow only one, even getting the shadow? I see it's only 1px, but I can't tell. If you hit F12 and use the Select Element tool to select it, does it show that it's getting the CSS you're trying to apply?

Comment: duplicate of this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55001610/8620333 ?

Comment: Given your use of `text-shadow` seems to be to achieve a stroke/outline around the text, have you considered just using `text-stroke`? It does, admittedly, have less browser support: https://caniuse.com/#search=text-stroke

Comment: @Robert I rather use a combination of text-shadow and linear-gradient. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55001610/8620333) here is an idea where you will need to duplicate the text:

```css
h1 {
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-size:60px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position:relative;
  margin:20px;
}
h1::before,
h1::after {
  content:attr(data-text);
}
h1::after {
  color:#fff; /*use white*/
  /*create the stroke around text*/
  text-shadow:
    1px 0  0px #000,
    0 1px 0px #000,
    1px 1px 0px #000,
    -1px 0 0px #000,
    0 -1px 0px #000,
    -1px -1px 0px #000,
    -1px 1px 0px #000,
    1px -1px 0px #000;
  mix-blend-mode: darken; /*everything is more dark than white so we always see the background */
}
h1::before {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom,yellow 50%, red 51%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  color:transparent;
}
```

```html
<h1 data-text="Heading 1"></h1>
```

Comment: A similar solution that also relies on `content` but only a single element: https://www.viget.com/articles/background-clip-text-shadow-gradients/

Comment: @Robert I am also using a singe element ;) I simply forget to remove the extra wrapper I took from my previous answer (edited)

Answer (score -1):

Where you have `background: linear-gradient(to top, black 50%, orange 50%);`, you should replace it with `bottom,`,
and where you have `1px 0 black`, you should get rid of `black`.

```html
<style>   
h1 {
  font-size: 72px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, black 50%, orange 50%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  text-shadow: -1px 0, 0 1px, 1px 0, 0 -1px
}
</style>
<h1>Heading 1</h1>
```

### Changes:

`background: -webkit-linear-gradient(`**`bottom,`**`black 50%, orange 50%);`
`text-shadow: -1px 0`<del>`black`</del>`, 0 1px`<del>`black`</del>`, 1px 0`<del>`black`</del>`, 0 -1px`<del>`black`</del>`;